# I'm mapping through a list of comments and I am returning a component. is there a way I could select every even one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm mapping through an array of comments and I am returning the same component that handles the data passed to it. It is kind of confusing because I can not tell which is odd or even and I need to style it based on that.

```
      <div className="comments">
        <h3>comments</h3>
        //here
        <Comment />
      </div>
```

if it were like this, I would have known what to do

```
      <div className="comments">
        <h3>comments</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>You look good!</li>
          <li>You are amazing!</li>
          <li>What  a wonderful project!</li>
          <li>Are you free tomorrow? let's cook.</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_. If there's no problem to summarize then you might want to have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: CSS has suitable selectors for that, all methods on `Array` that iterate over the elements of an array provide the index of the current element as argument, ... -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Depending on what element is being returned from your comment component: `.comments p:nth-child(even)` - here `Comment` returns a paragraph element which CSS can style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a prop into the component and use it to style it. For example:

```
const Comment = ({customClass, data}) =>{
  return (<div className = {customClass}> {data} </div>)
}
Const App = () =>{
//Example data Arr
const dataArr = ["hello", "bye"]
return (<div className="comments">
        <h3>comments</h3>
        {dataArr.map((data, idx) => <Comment
customClass = {idx % 2 === 0 ? "Custom Class" : ""} data={data} />}
      </div>)
}
```

However, you can also look at the `<Comment/>` component and see what html it returns, and style through css selectors like [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: black;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: red;
}
```

The latter is more peformant on browsers so I would attempt that first. If you need more fine grain control over determining the styles, you can try the former to attach custom class names

Answer (score 0):

Using JS you need to loop through all `li` elements and as per their `index` order, you can style them. But you can do it using CSS in a more simpler way. I would recommend that.

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div className="comments">
    <h3>comments</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>You look good!</li>
      <li>You are amazing!</li>
      <li>What  a wonderful project!</li>
      <li>Are you free tomorrow? let's cook.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the list with respect to add/even.

```
li:nth-child(even) {        
    background-color: antiquewhite;
 }
li:nth-child(odd) {        
    background-color: red;
 }
```